# Is there any way to restore only whatsapp data from encrypted itune backup?

Tags: ios, itunes, backup, restore

I have changed my iPhone from iPhone7 32Gb to iPhone7 128Gb. I backed up my old iPhone running iOS 13.5 using iTunes and try to restore that backup in new iPhone running iOS 14.0.1. the problem is that when restore backup process finished my iPhone went into Apple logo boot loop so I have to reinstall iOS 14.0.1 using iTunes. I tried to restore twice but every times I ended up in boot loop problem and have to reinstall iOS. I badly need my WhatsApp data so is there any way or 3rd party application to restore just WhatsApp data from my encrypted iTunes backup?

Comment: Reset the new iPhone and try device-to-device migration: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216

Comment: If you still have the old iPhone: can you upgrade it to iOS14 first?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have sold my old phone so all I got is different iTune backups. I actually tried 2 different backups to restore but every time ended up in boot loop!!!

Comment: WhatsApp allows a backup of its own - could you do that from your old phone

Answer (score -1):

There is a company called [BackupTrans](https://www.backuptrans.com/) that promises to be able to recover lost data from backups. I didn't try what you are suggesting, but I successfully transfered WhatsApp data from an android phone to iPhones 3 times using their "android whatsapp to iphone transfer" programme. You could try to do some research on their products, maybe there is something useful for your case.